# Randomly replace percentage of elements in matrix per existing values

Tags: matlab, random, replace, element

is there a sensible way to replace *x*% of each value in matrix/vector with a new value, and have the the element(s) to be changed be selected randomly?  That is, in *A*, if I wanted to change 20% of the values (1 element per existing value) to the value 5, how do I make sure that each of the 5 elements per existing value in *A* has an equal probability of changing to the new value (e.g. 5)?  I would appreciate some guidance on a method to complete the task described above.

Thank you kindly.

```
% Example Matrix
% M = 5;
% N = 5;
% A = zeros(M, N);
A = [0 0 0 0 0;
     1 1 1 1 1;
     2 2 2 2 2;
     3 3 3 3 3;
     4 4 4 4 4];   

% Example Matrix with 20% of elements per value replaced with the value '5'
A = [0 0 5 0 0;
     1 5 1 1 1;
     2 5 2 2 2;
     3 3 3 3 5;
     4 4 5 4 4];
```

Comment: Are you meaning that you want to change every value on a row if you change it at all?

Comment: @Pearsonartphoto No, I just want to change the 1 or more elements not the entire row.  The number of elements will depend on the percent _x_.

Comment: So you are wanting to change the numbers row by row in a fixed percentage way, randomly? IE, if the number is 20%, you will always change 1 element of each row?

Comment: @Pearsonartphoto Right.  The random part, would be which of the elements in that row get changed.  So 20% would mean one element from each row in a 5x5 such as _A_ should be changed to a new value.  However, if the percent to change was 4% then only one element in the entire 5x5 would be changed to a new value.  Thanks again for you assistance.

Comment: It is much easier, and usually better, to evaluate each value independently, as my answer does. Still, if you wish to do such a system, essentially you will have to randomly determine which row to slice. I don't know how you would do something like 19% off hand. Hmmm...

Comment: @Pearsonartphoto I think I could make the each value evaluation work once I can get the code you provided me below to be operational.  In fact, as you suggest, I think it too might be better.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using information from [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/54193-replace-percentage-of-existing-values-with-new-value) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13477287/permute-elements-within-rows-of-matrix/13477565#13477565) I was able to achieve my objective.  The code below will replace x% of each value in matrix with a new value and then randomize its location within that value in the matrix.

```
M = 5;
N = 5;
A = zeros(M, N);
PC = 20; % percent to change
nCells = round(100/PC); % # of cells to replace with new value
A = [0 0 0 0 0;
     1 1 1 1 1;
     2 2 2 2 2;
     3 3 3 3 3;
     4 4 4 4 4]; 
A2 = A+1; % Pad the cell values for calculations (bc of zero)
newvalue = 6;
a=hist(A2(:),5);% determine qty of each value
for i=1:5
    % find 1st instance of each value and convert to newvalue
    A2(find(A2==i,round(a(i)/nCells)))=newvalue;
end;
out = A2-1; % remove padding
[~,idx] = sort(rand(M,N),2); % convert column indices into linear indices
idx = (idx-1)*M + ndgrid(1:M,1:N); %rearrange each newvalue to be random
A = out;
A(:) = A(idx);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using logical arrays and a random number generated, like this:

```
vals_to_change=rand(size(A,1),size(A,2))<p;
A(vals_to_change)=rand(sum(vals_to_change),1);
```

Comment: thanks for the response.  If I run the code above, using p = 0.10 the result (vals_to_change) varied (n=10) from no elements with a value of 1, to 5 elements with a value of 1, sometimes in the same row.  The second line of code above results in a error message "Undefined function 'RND' for input arguments of type 'double'."  I don't think help rnd, does not come with anything in matlab.  I have read the documentation of binornd and have tinkered with variations in the code you have pasted, but I am not sure what the code is supposed to do.  Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: Try my latest change. Sorry, occasionally I mix up programming languages slightly...

Comment: the code above, using matrix _A_ results in the following errors: "Improper assignment with rectangular empty matrix." and "Improper assignment with rectangular empty matrix."  Please advise. I am using MATLAB 2011b.