# Permute elements within rows of matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, element, permutation

I have a matrix *A*

```
A = [0 0 0 0 1; 0 0 0 0 2; 0 1 2 3 4];
```

and I would like to randomly permute the elements within each row.  For example, matrix *A2*

```
A2 = [1 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 2 0; 4 1 3 2 0]; % example of desired output
```

I can do this with a vector:

```
Av = [0 1 2 3 4];
Bv = Av(randperm(5));
```

But I am unsure how to do this a row at time for a matrix and to only permute the elements within a given row.  Is this possible to do?  I could construct a matrix from many permuted vectors, but I would prefer not to do it this way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `sort` on a random array of any size (which is what `randperm` does). After that, all you need to do is some index-trickery to properly reshuffle the array

```
A = [0 0 0 0 1; 0 0 0 0 2; 0 1 2 3 4];
[nRows,nCols] = size(A);

[~,idx] = sort(rand(nRows,nCols),2);

%# convert column indices into linear indices
idx = (idx-1)*nRows + ndgrid(1:nRows,1:nCols);

%# rearrange A
B = A;
B(:) = B(idx)

B =

     0     0     1     0     0
     0     2     0     0     0
     2     1     3     4     0
```

Comment: Note that for older versions of matlab you can make it work by replacing `~` by `XXX`

Comment: Thanks @Jonas.  I definitely need to learn more about indexing and its trickery.